# How to create a status check on a schedule? API Woocommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

After sending the order for an external delivery service, I want to set up a check of its status. And if his status has changed, then change it in Woocommerce.

I have set up sending order data to an external delivery service.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_shiping');
function send_order_to_shiping( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_data = $order->get_data();

    // Get order details
    $parametr['sale_amount'] = $order_data['discount_total'];
    $parametr['street'] = $order_data['billing']['address_1'];
    $parametr['home'] = $order_data['billing']['address_2'];

    $order_id = $order_data['id'];

    foreach ($parametr as $key => $value){ 
        $data .= "&parametr[".$key."]=".$value."";
    } 

    // Send data
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.example.com/api/index.php?new_order");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
}
```

When I send the order (example id 555) I get the answer `echo $result;`:
id_order from delivery service - 7273896.

`echo $result;` show:

```
{"result":"success","order_id":7273896,"order_number":10}
```

So I have order id in Woocommerce - 555, order id in delivery service 7273896.

Logically, I need to save this in the order metadata and make a status check separately with this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part one of your question, I would suggest using a plugin called WP Crontrol. You can create a cron job to call a function with your delivery service API.

You'll need to create a rule to allow a cron every 15 minutes. Go to Settings->Cron Schedules to add a 15-minute interval rule. Add a cron job in Tools->Cron Events. Give it a hook name and an action. You can also include args that go to your function if needed.

In functions.php, add matching code for your new cron job to run. Here's an example:

```
add_action( 'check_status_hook', 'checkStatusAction' );
function checkStatusAction ($args) {
    //run your code here or call it from here
}
```

Part 2 of your question...I can't offer any help. I haven't worked in WooCommerce to even know where the order status is set, or if you can simply change a single status value without upsetting something else.

Answer (score 1):

To update the status of an order

```
$order = new WC_Order( $parametr['order_id'] );

$order->update_status('wc-cancelled');
```

An overview of order statussen can be retrieved from 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_order_statuses.html#88-106